# Show active record entries inside 'f.collection_select' on edit (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-select, collection-select

I have a Rails 5 app.

`template _form`

```
- if current_user&.super_admin
  .form-group.has-feedback
    .text-muted
      = f.label 'Which users should see this?'
    = f.collection_select(:user_templates, User.all, :id, :name, { include_hidden: false }, multiple: 'true', class: 'select')
```

It's a multiple select form. When submitting the form I send an array of users to my controller and save it in my `user_template` table, which creates a new row for every users that was selected. Works perfectly.

However, when I **edit** the specific template I would like to show the users that was saved the first time. I can easily query them in the db and get all the right users but I cannot show them as `selected` in the multiple dropdown.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select#632--selected

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Iceman. I have tried adding `{ :selected => User.all }` and I would expect all users to be selected in the dropdown. However, none are selected. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: Got it to work mate. This is my new f.collection_select: `= f.collection_select :user_templates, User.all, :id, :name, { :selected => User.all.map(&:id)}, multiple: 'true', class: 'select'`

Comment: Great, I also think the shorthand `User.all.ids` works, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Just tried and it does indeed work. Cheers.

Comment: @Iceman: I'm having issues with my query for the active record entries. I have the following tables `template`, `user`, `template_user` and user has_many templates through: `template_user`. I would like to return a list of all the users for a given template id. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you have in your `Template`model a reverse of that relationship, `has many :template_users` and `has_many :users, through: :template_users`. It's just a matter of `Template.find(1).users`

Comment: Doh! So simple. Makes sense. Works. Thanks.